# kotlinとJacksonを用いてjsonデータをLocalTimeにシリアライズしたいのですが、実装できません

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

プログラミン初学者です。
タイトルの通りkotlinとJacksonを用いてLocalTimeなどのデータをシリアライズしたのですが
うまく実装できません。ご回答お願いします。

書いたコード

```
JacksonPractice.kt
@RestController
@RequestMapping("json")
class JacksonPractice {

    @PostMapping(
            value=[""],
            consumes = ["application/json"]
    )
    fun postJsonData(@RequestBody json: String) {
        println("called getJsonData")
        println("----- json data -----")
        println(json)
        println("")
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        val jsonData = mapper.readValue<JsonData>(json)
        println("----- json serialize -----")
        println(jsonData)
    }
}
```

JsonDataModel.kt(データクラス)

```
package practice.kotlinjackson.model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalTimeDeserializer
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalTime

data class JsonData(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)
        @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer::class)
        val date : LocalDateTime,
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
        val time: LocalTime,
        val jsonDataDetail: JsonDataDetail
)

data class JsonDataDetail(
        val detail: String
)
```

guild.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
}

group = "practice.kotlin-jackson"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.5")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

リクエストは下記のjsonデータをpostmanからリクエストしています

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "kotlin jackson",
    "date": "2017-11-13T06:40:00Z",
    "time": "10:00:00",
    "jsonDataDetail": {
        "detail": "data detail"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlinの data class を直接扱うためには `KotlinModule` の登録も必要のようです:

```
    fun postJsonData(@RequestBody json: String) {
        println("called getJsonData")
        println("----- json data -----")
        println(json)
        println("")
        val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModules(KotlinModule(), JavaTimeModule())
        val jsonData = mapper.readValue<JsonData>(json)
        println("----- json serialize -----")
        println(jsonData)
    }
```

- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin
- https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/jackson-kotlin

---

Spring Bootにデフォルトで組み込まれているメッセージコンバータに任せるのも一般的でしょう:

```
    fun postJsonData(@RequestBody jsonData: JsonData) {
        println("----- json serialize -----")
        println(jsonData)
    }
```

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

備忘録の為に最終的に解決したコードを記載します
https://github.com/ShutoKeisuke/kotlin-jackson-practice

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("json")
class JacksonPractice {

    @PostMapping(
            value=[""],
            consumes = ["application/json"]
    )
    fun postJsonData(@RequestBody json: String) {
        println("called getJsonData")
        println("----- json data -----")
        println(json)
        println("")
        val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
        mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        val jsonData = mapper.readValue<JsonData>(json)
        println("----- json serialize -----")
        println(jsonData)
    }

    @PostMapping(value = ["converter"])
    fun postMessageConverter(@RequestBody jsonData: JsonData) {
        println("----- json serialize -----")
        println(jsonData)
    }
}
```

Data Class

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalTime

data class JsonData(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
//        @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)
//        @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer::class)
        val date : LocalDateTime,
//        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm")
        val time: LocalTime,
        val jsonDataDetail: JsonDataDetail
)

data class JsonDataDetail(
        val detail: String
)
```

build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
}

group = "practice.kotlin-jackson"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.5")
    // ↓たぶんいらない
    implementation ("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.+")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Json ※Postmanからリクエストして確認

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "kotlin jackson",
    "date": "2017-11-13T06:40:00Z",
    "time": "10:00",
    "jsonDataDetail": {
        "detail": "data detail"
    }
}
```